# Working of the for loop to get the minimum value

Tags: salesforce, apex

It may sound little weird but can someone please explain how the below loop manages to get the lowest value

```
Decimal LowestPrice;
 //for loop to find the smallest value
    for(Integer i = 0;i<leadingPrice.size();i++){
        //no idea how the below line is getting the lowest value 
        if(LowestPrice == null || leadingPrice.get(i) < LowestPrice){
            lowestprice = leadingPrice.get(i);

        }
```

LeadingPrice is a List of Decimals and above loop is assigning the lowest value to the variable lowestprice, can someone please explain the working of above loop 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(LowestPrice == null || leadingPrice.get(i) < LowestPrice){
        lowestprice = leadingPrice.get(i);

   }
```

It checks if LowestPrice is assigned or not by using `Lowestprice == null`. If LowestPrice is assigned then checks if current index (`leadingPrice.get(i)`) is smaller than LowestPrice. If `leadingPrice.get(i)` is smaller, then it assigned to LowestPrice

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response but the lowestprice variable is null and how an arithmetic comparison can take place between decimal and null?

Comment: null means not assigned or zero. So when LowestPrice is null first leadingPrice is assigned

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer is satisfied you please click the checkbox button

Answer (score 0):

First time through the loop, LowestPrice is null(I don't like this assumption but that is the way the code is written) so it sets LowestPrice to the first entry in the array leadingPrice.  Each subsequent time through the for loop, the LowestPrice is compared to the next entry in the leadingPrice Array. If the new entry is lower, then LowestPrice is updated to the new one. If not, it stays the current.  After a complete trip through the entire array you are guaranteed to to have the lowest price.

A more concise way to state it is: You assume the first entry is lowest and then read through the entire array looking for a lower prices. Every time you find one you replace your current lowest candidate.

Comment: Thank you so much, Thomas, LowestPrice is certainly null and in if statement I have observed there is an arithmetic comparison between the decimal and the null value(lowsetPrice) but I am not able to understand how a comparison between null and decimal is possible and also how the lowestprice is getting assigned with the frist value of the list.

Comment: Thank you so much, Thomas, I have got the answer.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If I was writing that code I would not have assumed null on a newly created variable.  I've been bitten by that before.  I would have initialized LowestPrice = leadingPrice(0) and then started my for loop at 1.  That way the if statement just needs to be if(leadingPrice.get(i) < LowestPrice){...}